# How much reputation can I earn in a single day?

Tags: discussion

Daily cap is 200, but because of bounties and accepted answers it is extended.

So how much can I earn a day?

Maximum I saw is [871](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=26).

Comment: Only saw 3 pages, but [491 is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=3).

Comment: @brasofilo: with bounties people have earned over 1000.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already list the limitation that exists and explain how you could still earn more than that. Theoretically there is no limit to the amount of reputation one could earn, but earning it will become more unlikely the higher you get.